# Oracle build order and PL/SQL package dependencies

Tags: oracle, plsql, dependencies

I'm trying to build up a list of PL/SQL package dependencies so that I can help set up an automated build script for my packages to run on the test server. Is there a way to start with a single package (a "root" package identified by name, ideally) and then find all of the dependencies, and the order they must be compiled in? 
Dependencies are already fully resolved in my personal schema (so at least I have somewhere to start - but where do I go next?).

(Oracle 10.2)

**EDIT:**

The build tool that is being used will use the build order and will retreive those files in order from source control, and then pass them to Oracle to compile (the actual build tool itself is written in Python or Java or both - I don't have access to the source). Basically, the build tool needs as input a list of files to compile *in the order they must be compiled in*, and acces to those files in source control. If it has that, everything will work quite nicely.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the neat scripts. Unfortunately, the build process is mostly out of my hands. The process is based around a build tool which was built by the vendor of the product we are integrating with, which is why the only inputs I can give to the build process are a list of files in the order they need to be built in. If there is a compiler error, the build tool fails, we have to manually submit a request for a new build. So a list of files in the order they should be compiled is important.

**EDIT:**

Found this: http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/code/tips2004/091304.html
Gives me the dependencies of any object. Now I just need to get the ordering right... If I get something working I'll post it here.

**EDIT:** (with code!)

I know that in general, this sort of thing is not necessary for Oracle, but for anyone who's still interested...

I have cobbled together a little script that seems to be able to get a build order such that all packages will be built in the correct order with no dependency-related errors (with respect to pacakges) the first time around:

```
declare

    type t_dep_list is table of varchar2(40) index by binary_integer;
    dep_list t_dep_list;
    i number := 1;
    cursor c_getObjDepsByNameAndType is
    --based on a query found here: http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/code/tips2004/091304.html
        select lvl, u.object_id, u.object_type, LPAD(' ', lvl) || object_name obj
        FROM (SELECT level lvl, object_id
               FROM SYS.public_dependency s
               START WITH s.object_id = (select object_id
                                         from user_objects
                                         where object_name = UPPER(:OBJECT_NAME)
                                               and object_type = UPPER(:OBJECT_TYPE))
               CONNECT BY s.object_id = PRIOR referenced_object_id
               GROUP BY level, object_id) tree, user_objects u
        WHERE tree.object_id = u.object_id
              and u.object_type like 'PACKAGE%' --only look at packages, not interested in other types of objects
        ORDER BY lvl desc;

    function fn_checkInList(in_name in varchar2) return boolean is
    begin
        for j in 1 .. dep_list.count loop
            if dep_list(j) = in_name then
                return true;
            end if;
        end loop;
        return false;
    end;



    procedure sp_getDeps(in_objID in user_objects.object_id%type, in_name in varchar2) is
        cursor c_getObjDepsByID(in_objID in user_objects.object_id%type) is
        --based on a query found here: http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/code/tips2004/091304.html
            select lvl, u.object_id, u.object_type, LPAD(' ', lvl) || object_name obj
            FROM (SELECT level lvl, object_id
                   FROM SYS.public_dependency s
                   START WITH s.object_id = (select uo.object_id
                                             from user_objects uo
                                             where uo.object_name =
                                                   (select object_name from user_objects uo where uo.object_id = in_objID)
                                                   and uo.object_type = 'PACKAGE BODY')
                   CONNECT BY s.object_id = PRIOR referenced_object_id
                   GROUP BY level, object_id) tree, user_objects u
            WHERE tree.object_id = u.object_id
                  and u.object_id <> in_objID --exclude self (requested Object ID) from list.
            ORDER BY lvl desc;
    begin
        --loop through the dependencies
        for r in c_getObjDepsByID(in_objID) loop
            if fn_checkInList(trim(r.obj)) = false and (r.object_type = 'PACKAGE' or r.object_type = 'PACKAGE BODY') and
               trim(r.obj) <> trim(in_name) then
                dbms_output.put_line('checking deps of: ' || r.obj || ' ' || r.object_id || ' level: ' || r.lvl);
                --now for each dependency, check the sub-dependency
                sp_getDeps(r.object_id, trim(r.obj));
                --add the object to the dependency list.
                dep_list(i) := trim(r.obj);
                i := i + 1;
            end if;
        end loop;
    exception
        when NO_DATA_FOUND then
            dbms_output.put_line('no more data for: ' || in_objID);
    end;

begin

    for r in c_getObjDepsByNameAndType loop
        dbms_output.put_line('top-level checking deps of: ' || r.obj || ' ' || r.object_id || ' level: ' || r.lvl);
        sp_getDeps(r.object_id, trim(r.obj));
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line('dep count: ' || dep_list.count);
    for j in 1 .. dep_list.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line('obj: ' || j || ' ' || dep_list(j));
    end loop;
end;
```

I know it's not the prettiest code (globals all over the place, etc... ugh), and I'll probably repost it if I can get a chance this afternoon to clean it up, but right now, it produces a build order that seems to run the first time with no problems.

`:OBJECT_NAME` should be the root object that you want to trace all dependencies and build order of. For me, this is a main package with a single method that is the entry point to the rest of the system.

`:OBJECT_TYPE` I have mostly restricted to `PACKAGE BODY`, but it shouldn't be too much work to include other types, such as triggers.

One last thing, the object specified by `:OBJECT_NAME` will not appear in the output, but it should be the last item, so you'll have to add that to your build list manually.

**UPDATE:** I just discovered `user_dependencies` and `all_dependencies`, this code could probably be made much simpler now.

Comment: do you mean Oracle PL/SQL packages?

Comment: Only way I've done it is to script it, and test deploying to a fresh schema.  Reorder the packages in the script as needed based on errors...

Comment: I forgot to mention that spc's should be loaded before bdy's to help with package.function/stored proc resolution.  You are separating them, not loading a single file (file extension escapes me ATM) - right?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Yes, we know we have to compile all specifications before any bodies. The main issue is the order of the specifications. Yes, they are in separate files from the bodies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actual solution: The script above seems to give the correct build order. Could probably be rewritten "nicer", but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader. ;)

After some discussion, the build tool will perform *n* (4, actually) builds in a row before reporting errors. This would also help resolve dependency compile errors if the build order is wrong, but I'd rather just get the build order right the first time around.

Answer (score 10):

If you're really dealing with just PL/SQL packages you do not need to sweat the build order.  Just build all the package specifications first.  Then you can deploy all the package bodies and they will compile, because their dependencies are the package specs.

If you happen to have some package specs which do depend on other specs - if you have packages which declare, say, constants, subtypes or ref cursors which are used in the signatures of packaged procedures - then you need to build those package specs first.  But there should be few enough of them that you can arrange them in the build script by hand.

**edit**

> It looks like they wil be doing
>   incremental AND "clean-sweep" builds,
>   so the build order will matter most
>   for when they clean out the
>   environment and rebuild it.

That doesn't alter anything.

Here is an extended example.  I have a schema with three packages....

```
SQL> select object_name, object_type, status
  2  from user_objects
  3  order by 1, 2
  4  /

OBJECT_NAME     OBJECT_TYPE     STATUS
--------------- --------------- -------
PKG1            PACKAGE         VALID
PKG1            PACKAGE BODY    VALID
PKG2            PACKAGE         VALID
PKG2            PACKAGE BODY    VALID
PKG3            PACKAGE         VALID
PKG3            PACKAGE BODY    VALID

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

The interesting thing is that a procedure in PKG1 calls a procedure from PKG2, a procedure in PKG2 calls a procedure from PKG3 and a procedure in PKG3 calls a procedure from PKG1.

**Q.**  How does that circular dependency work?
**A.**  It's not a circular dependency....

```
SQL> select name, type, referenced_name, referenced_type
  2  from user_dependencies
  3  where referenced_owner = user
  4  /

NAME            TYPE            REFERENCED_NAME REFERENCED_TYPE
--------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
PKG1            PACKAGE BODY    PKG1            PACKAGE
PKG1            PACKAGE BODY    PKG2            PACKAGE
PKG2            PACKAGE BODY    PKG2            PACKAGE
PKG2            PACKAGE BODY    PKG3            PACKAGE
PKG3            PACKAGE BODY    PKG3            PACKAGE
PKG3            PACKAGE BODY    PKG1            PACKAGE

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

All the dependent objects are the package bodies, all the referenced objects are the packaged specs.  Consequently, if I trash'n'rebuild the schema it really doesn't matter what order I use.  First we trash ...

```
SQL> drop package pkg1
  2  /

Package dropped.

SQL> drop package pkg2
  2  /

Package dropped.

SQL> drop package pkg3
  2  /

Package dropped.

SQL>
```

Then we rebuild ...

```
SQL> create or replace package pkg3 is
  2      procedure p5;
  3      procedure p6;
  4  end pkg3;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package pkg2 is
  2      procedure p3;
  3      procedure p4;
  4  end pkg2;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package pkg1 is
  2      procedure p1;
  3      procedure p2;
  4  end pkg1;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg2 is
  2      procedure p3 is
  3      begin
  4          pkg3.p5;
  5      end p3;
  6      procedure p4 is
  7      begin
  8          dbms_output.put_line('PKG2.P4');
  9      end p4;
 10  end pkg2;
 11  /

Package body created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg3 is
  2      procedure p5 is
  3      begin
  4          dbms_output.put_line('PKG3.P5');
  5      end p5;
  6      procedure p6 is
  7      begin
  8          pkg1.p1;
  9      end p6;
 10  end pkg3;
 11  /

Package body created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg1 is
  2      procedure p1 is
  3      begin
  4          dbms_output.put_line('PKG1.P1');
  5      end p1;
  6      procedure p2 is
  7      begin
  8          pkg2.p4;
  9      end p2;
 10  end pkg1;
 11  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

The order of the individual objects is irrelevant.  Just build the package specs before the package bodies.  Although even that does not really matter...

```
SQL> create or replace package pkg4 is
  2      procedure p7;
  3  end pkg4;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg4 is
  2      procedure p7 is
  3      begin
  4          dbms_output.put_line('PKG4.P7::'||constants_pkg.whatever);
  5      end p7;
  6  end pkg4;
  7  /

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PACKAGE BODY PKG4:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/9      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
4/43     PLS-00201: identifier 'CONSTANTS_PKG.WHATEVER' must be declared
SQL>
```

`PKG4` is INVALID because we have not built `CONSTANTS_PKG` yet.

```
SQL> create or replace package constants_pkg is
  2      whatever constant varchar2(20) := 'WHATEVER';
  3  end constants_pkg;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> select object_name, object_type, status
  2  from user_objects
  3  where status != 'VALID'
  4  order by 1, 2
  5  /

OBJECT_NAME     OBJECT_TYPE     STATUS
--------------- --------------- -------
PKG4            PACKAGE BODY    INVALID

SQL> 
SQL> set serveroutput on size unlimited
SQL> exec pkg4.p7
PKG4.P7::WHATEVER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select object_name, object_type, status
  2  from user_objects
  3  where status != 'VALID'
  4  order by 1, 2
  5  /

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Anything built using `CREATE OR REPLACE` is always created, it is just marked as INVALID if there are errors.  As soon as we execute it, directly or indirectly, the database compiles it for us.  So, order does not matter.  Really it doesn't.

If the idea of finishing a build with invalid objects concerns you - and I have some sympathy with that, we are told not to live with broken windows - you can use the `utlrp` script or in 11g [the UTL_RECOMP package](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_recomp.htm#i999843); either approach requires a SYSDBA account.

**edit 2**

> The process is based around a build
>   tool which was built by the vendor of
>   the product we are integrating with,
>   which is why the only inputs I can
>   give to the build process are a list
>   of files in the order they need to be
>   built in. If there is a compiler
>   error, the build tool fails, we have
>   to manually submit a request for a new
>   build.

This is a political problem not a technical one.  Which isn't to say that political problems can't be resolved with a technical fix, just that the technical fix is not the best tool for the job.  Good luck.

Comment: I started doing this by hand, and realized that we will have to keep doing it by hand as the project progresses and new packages are added (and there WILL be new packages, probably late spring - I'd like to have something automated before then).

Comment: By all means automate the build.  But if you add a package now, you just need to add it to the end of the build script.  The dependency order really doesn't matter with packages.

Comment: If they were building the code incrementally, I think you'd be right. It looks like they wil be doing incremental AND "clean-sweep" builds, so the build order will matter most for when they clean out the environment and rebuild it.

Comment: After pushing all the packages in, if you look at the schema, many may appear uncompiled.  As was mentioned, Oracle should compile them automatically on first use, but if you want some more comfort, just use dbms_utility.compile_schema(...) to compile your schema.  Its probably similar to UTLRP, but doesn't require SYSDBA privs and only affects one schema.

Comment: Those are some very good points. We also had a sort of victory with the tool itself: We just discovered that we can request up to 4 PL/SQL recompiles "under the covers", and only the errors that persist after the 4th pass are reported. I'd still like a mostly-correct build order, as it could help the 4 passes go a little faster.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the following script from http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/RecompilingInvalidSchemaObjects.php

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
BEGIN
  FOR cur_rec IN (SELECT owner,
                         object_name,
                         object_type,
                         DECODE(object_type, 'PACKAGE', 1,
                                             'PACKAGE BODY', 2, 2) AS recompile_order
                  FROM   dba_objects
                  WHERE  object_type IN ('PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE BODY')
                  AND    status != 'VALID'
                  ORDER BY 4)
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      IF cur_rec.object_type = 'PACKAGE' THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER ' || cur_rec.object_type || 
            ' "' || cur_rec.owner || '"."' || cur_rec.object_name || '" COMPILE';
      ElSE
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER PACKAGE "' || cur_rec.owner || 
            '"."' || cur_rec.object_name || '" COMPILE BODY';
      END IF;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(cur_rec.object_type || ' : ' || cur_rec.owner || 
                             ' : ' || cur_rec.object_name);
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Interesting, however I am not sure this will provide an actual build order.

Answer (score 1):

One little thing to watch out for when walking the dependency tree.  Dependencies for uncompiled programs don't show...

```
SQL> drop package constants_pkg
  2  /

Package dropped.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg4 is
  2      procedure p7 is
  3      begin
  4          dbms_output.put_line('PKG4.P7::'||zzz_constants_pkg.whatever);
  5      end p7;
  6  end pkg4;
  7  /

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PACKAGE BODY PKG4:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/9      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
4/43     PLS-00201: identifier 'ZZZ_CONSTANTS_PKG.WHATEVER' must be
         declared

SQL>
```

So, the body for `PKG4` is INVALID because `ZZZ_CONSTANTS_PKG` doesn't exist.

```
SQL> create or replace package zzz_constants_pkg is
  2      whatever constant varchar2(20) := 'WHATEVER';
  3  end zzz_constants_pkg;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL>
```

But the body for `PKG4` is still INVALID so the following query does not return its dependency on `ZZZ_CONSTANTS_PKG`  ....

```
SQL> select name, type, referenced_name, referenced_type
  2  from user_dependencies
  3  where referenced_owner = user
  4  /

NAME            TYPE            REFERENCED_NAME   REFERENCED_TYPE
--------------- --------------- ----------------- ---------------
PKG1            PACKAGE BODY    PKG1              PACKAGE
PKG1            PACKAGE BODY    PKG2              PACKAGE
PKG2            PACKAGE BODY    PKG2              PACKAGE
PKG2            PACKAGE BODY    PKG3              PACKAGE
PKG3            PACKAGE BODY    PKG3              PACKAGE
PKG3            PACKAGE BODY    PKG1              PACKAGE
PKG4            PACKAGE BODY    PKG4              PACKAGE

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now let's compile `PKG4` and re-query the dependencies ....

```
SQL> alter package pkg4 compile body;

Package body altered.

SQL> select name, type, referenced_name, referenced_type
  2  from user_dependencies
  3  where referenced_owner = user
  4  /

NAME            TYPE            REFERENCED_NAME   REFERENCED_TYPE
--------------- --------------- ----------------- ---------------
PKG1            PACKAGE BODY    PKG1              PACKAGE
PKG1            PACKAGE BODY    PKG2              PACKAGE
PKG2            PACKAGE BODY    PKG2              PACKAGE
PKG2            PACKAGE BODY    PKG3              PACKAGE
PKG3            PACKAGE BODY    PKG3              PACKAGE
PKG3            PACKAGE BODY    PKG1              PACKAGE
PKG4            PACKAGE BODY    PKG4              PACKAGE
PKG4            PACKAGE BODY    ZZZ_CONSTANTS_PKG PACKAGE

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a build order - just build the packages with "CREATE OR REPLACE..." on a file-by-file basis and then compile them in a two-level nested loop - each pass in the inner loop compiles everything that is still invalid and the outer loop is used to check the count of remaining invalid objects and set some sort of threshold for maximum executions of the inner loop.  In practice, I've never seen the number of passes needed be higher than three.

If you have multiple schemas involved in the dependencies, look into running Oracles utlrp.sql script, which works across schemas and sets up some infrastructure to manage the process - this needs a privileged account however.

Also, if you extend your source control to include views, be sure that the scripts use "CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW... " to create views which have unmet dependencies at the time of their creation.

Example script that I use:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
 cursor invalidObjCur is 
  select object_name, object_type
    from user_objects
    where status <> 'VALID'
    ;
 compileStmt varchar2(4000); 
 passCount pls_integer := 0;
 maxPasses pls_integer := 5;
 lastInvalidCount pls_integer := 32000; 
 objectCount pls_integer;
 continue boolean := TRUE;

begin
 dbms_output.enable(1000000);
 while (continue) loop
   passCount := passCount + 1;
   dbms_output.put_line('Pass '||passCount);
   objectCount := 0;
   for curRow in InvalidObjCur loop
    if curRow.object_type = 'PACKAGE BODY' then
        compileStmt := 'alter PACKAGE '||curRow.object_name||' compile body';
    else
        compileStmt := 'alter '||curRow.object_type||' '||
        chr(34)||curRow.object_name||chr(34)||' compile';
    end if;
    begin
      execute immediate compileStmt;
    exception when others then
      null;
    end;
   objectCount := objectCount + 1;
   end loop;
   dbms_output.put_line('Recompilations attempted: '||objectCount);
   continue := (passCount < maxPasses) and (objectCount < lastInvalidCount);
   lastInvalidCount := objectCount;
 end loop;
dbms_output.put_line('***** Remaining Invalid ********');
for curRow in InvalidObjCur loop
 dbms_output.put_line(curRow.object_type||' '||curRow.object_name);
end loop; 
dbms_output.put_line('********************************');
end;    
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following command to the top of your script:

SET VERIFY OFF

this will allow your scripts to run without validation and therefore can be run in any order.

You can later query DBA_ERRORS to get all errors and warnings in your packages, views and types.

Comment: The SQL Plus command `SET VERIFY OFF` *only* turns of verification of substitution variable values such as `&schema_name.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead for 11.1 and up.  Run the script in any order.
At the end issue the following command:
(Change the command parameters to suit your needs)

```
-- Compile invalid objects
EXEC DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(USER, FALSE);
```

More details on [DBMS_UTILITY.compile_scema](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/3583.dbms-utility-compile-schema.aspx)